# Unidentified package installing in my node_modules

Tags: node.js, npm, phantomjs, package.json

There is a package called `phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.16` that is continuously installing in my node_modules folder and I can't find the way to track it to know where it comes from. This package is deprecated already and it is throwing errors when I try to dockerize my nextjs project.
The error is telling my that this package does not have binary for my architecture `arm64` (I have a M1 MacOS):

```bash
102.1 [4/4] Building fresh packages...
104.7 error /usr/src/app/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt: Command failed.
104.7 Exit code: 1
104.7 Command: node install.js
104.7 Arguments: 
104.7 Directory: /usr/src/app/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt
104.7 Output:
104.7 PhantomJS not found on PATH
104.7 Unexpected platform or architecture: linux/arm64
104.7 It seems there is no binary available for your platform/architecture
104.7 Try to install PhantomJS globally
```

But that does not bother me, I just want to remove it or track the dependecy which is installing it. Is there a way to do that?
I already tried `yarn list` but it only shows the dependencies of this packages and not the one which is installing it:

```bash
├─ phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.16
│  ├─ fs-extra@1.0.0
│  └─ jsonfile@2.4.0
✨  Done in 0.39s.
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: You should run `npm install` inside docker instead of copying `node_modules` to the docker

Comment: You can try running `npx find-dependent phantomjs-prebuilt` in the directory where your `package-lock.json` is

Comment: I am not copying the node_modules, in fact is the `yarn install` command which is throwing that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using yarn try:

`yarn why phantomjs-prebuilt`

[Documentation](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/why/)

Comment: works like a charm! The dependency which was intalling `phantom-prebuilt` was `svg-sprite`  Thanks @Lalaluka